# How do I access my Django server from outside?

Tags: django

My computer is connected to our college's local network. I am able to access my django server in the same network from another computer. When I try to do the same from an outside internet connection, I get an " Webpage not found error" . I used the ip given by Whatsmyip.com to access it from outside. Also, I started the server using the command : python manage.py runserver 0:8000

Answer (score 2):

Use something like:

- LocalTunnel http://localtunnel.me/
- Ngrok https://ngrok.com/

These create a tunnel to your localhost. You cannot host from a common IP shared by an internal network. Read more about localhost here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Please note that the tools above allow you to share a link to your site and is mostly meant for development and testing. If you really want to host a Django server, either do it on an external server or contact your infrastructure team in college to see if they even allow such a thing.

For external hosting, Heroku (https://www.heroku.com) can be a good option with a reasonable free plan.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your college network. Often, computers in local networkds are behind a NAT (one single external ip for several clients). At this point, the request cannot be routed from out- to inside. Maybe a college technician can help you to route your page.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's first important to note that `manage.py runserver` is for **local** development. It is not meant to be used for deployment.

If you want to access your website from "outside", you should consider **deploying it**. You can then read more about this here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/

Also, like stated in other answers, depending on how is configured your college network, it may not be possible to access your development server from outside, because :

- It probably has NAT rules for local networks
- There are probably port restrictions and a firewall for outside access (usually college networks are very restrictive from inside AND from outside)